# How do i trade bitcoin with an altcoin if my wallet doesn't support that altcoin?

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-trade

Let's say i buy 1 bitcoin and i have it on my wallet. So let's say  bought that bitcoin to trade it for komodo. how do i trade it, i mean how will i get in the posession of the komodo if my current wallet doesn't support the komodo coin?

Answer (score 1):

Your coins will be held on the exchange site itself until you choose to withdraw them to your own wallet. If you want to withdraw them, you will have to create a wallet for the currency you have purchased, and use it to generate an address to withdraw to.

Comment: finally an awesomly good response. THANK YOU. now, what do you think is the best exchange platform that supports this type of exchange?

Comment: Which exchange is best is purely up to your own opinion :) remember to accept my answer if it satisfies your question btw